# Email notification on Profile Update

Tags: notification, profile

Is there a rationale for sending email notification to a user after he changed some information in his own profile?

**Example**

> Dear user, you have modified the credit cards in your travel profile.
>
> This message was automatically generated. Please do not reply; the
>   mailbox is not monitored.

Some websites and companies will send such notification email while others will not. I find them quite pointless, am I missing something?

Comment: If someone changed the password to your online banking, wouldn't you want to know?

Answer (score 4):

**For security purposes, an update is sometimes sent to make sure the user knows that an important modification has been made.**

When such a notification has been sent, it often says something along the lines of:

'A payment preference has been changed in your account'

along with a link or secondary statement telling the user if they made the change, they can dismiss this message. Otherwise sometimes there's a support link or way to contact and rectify the situation.

Dropbox for example has a page for when a password is reset, but it wasn't the account holder that initiated:

[If you get a password or email change notification but didn't reset it yourself](https://www.dropbox.com/help/security/unauthorized-account-information-changed)

There's a fine line between bugging people, and keeping them aware of things that have changed (perhaps not by them).

Comment: This, as an anecdote I was at work a while back when I got an email that my Steam password was changed. By the time I reset my password someone had killed a few characters  in a permadeath game that I spent a lot of money on. Had I not been notified and reset my password, ending their session, it couldve been a lot worse.